# Django collecting static from virtualenv app on apache wgsi

Tags: django, apache, autocomplete, virtualenv, static-libraries

I'm using autocomplete-light 3 in Django project. 
I publish production with an virtualenv.
Autocomplete-light come with some static file in.
I added in settings:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/......../........../myapp/static',
    '/home/myuser/.virtualenv/prd_vrt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dal/static',
    '/home/myuser/.virtualenv/prd_vrt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dal_select2/static',
)
```

but it was not enough to publish the static files.

If I include the file in my static folder it works.
I don't think this is the best solution ( not easy maintenance).

May I add some permission to apache?
Or what is the best way to archive this situation?

Comment: You shouldn't do any of that. If the app is included in INSTALLED_APPS its static files will be automatically included.

Comment: the app is included in INSTALLED_APPS: it work, bat the static part (the js and css files called in the page) is not avalable for the browser; everything work perfectly if I copy the static files in my app static folder.

Comment: Did you run collectstatic?